# Cant manage to format or remove legend in px.scatter

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, scatter-plot

I am trying to move the legend of a scatter plot a bit, but nothing seems to work.

this is the simple scatter plot.

```
fig_party_body = px.scatter(body_data, x= 'mean_stance', y = 'interest', color = 'mean_stance' )
fig_party_body
```

this is the scatter result:
[image]

now i want to move the legend, but i cant manage to do it with update layout -
for example, this code doesnt budge it at all no matter what i do (switch xanchor, fiddle with the x and y values):

```
fig_party_body.update_layout(
    legend=dict(
        x=1.02,  # Adjust the x position of the legend
        y=1.0,  # Adjust the y position of the legend
        borderwidth=2,  # Set legend border width
        xanchor='right',  # Set x anchor to the right side of legend
        yanchor='top'  # Set y anchor to the top of legend
    ))
```

even trying to remove it completely, with update_layout(showlegend = False) doesnt work! its still there.
what am i doing wrong? this is important for other, more intricate graphs i am building.
thank you!

Comment: This is not the legend but the colorbar, you want to update its x position, eg.  `fig.update_coloraxes(colorbar_x=1.05)` default is 1.02. @see https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/coloraxis/#layout-coloraxis-colorbar-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it the color bar without the legend that you want to move on the question? Then the setting is colorbar with colorscale.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color='petal_length')

fig.update_layout(
    coloraxis=dict(colorbar=dict(
        x=1.02,  # Adjust the x position of the legend
        y=1.0,  # Adjust the y position of the legend
        borderwidth=2,  # Set legend border width
        xanchor='right',  # Set x anchor to the right side of legend
        yanchor='top'  # Set y anchor to the top of legend
    ))
)

fig.show()
```

[image]